# Next 13 - useRouter from next/navigate is no more asyncronous?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In the NEXT 13, useRouter `push` method is no more asynchronous as it used to be in `next/router`. This creates an ambiguity where you cannot show a loading spinner until the navigation is complete. Is there a way to address this or any workaround?

As asked in the comments, here's the code I am referring to:

with `next/router`:

```
import {useRouter} from 'next/router'

...

const redirectUser = (href: string) => {
    dispatch(setLoading(true))
    router.push(href).then(() => setLoading(false))
}
```

However this is what happens with `next/navigation`:

```
import {useRouter} from 'next/navigation'

...

const redirectUser = (href: string) => {
    dispatch(setLoading(true))
    router.push(href) // .then(() => setLoading(false))
    // then method not supported as `push` is no more async
    // how to restore the state now?
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code to show the problem you are facing? Preferably codesandbox. I do not understand where you want to show the loader

Comment: Hi @TusharShahi I have updated the question as you asked

Comment: setLoading(false) in the next line is not working out for you?

Comment: `.then` is not supported. I am getting type error saying its not a promise